# Java-Spark: how to get a Dataset<Row> column's value when iterating in a loop and use it in when().otherwise()?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `Dataset<Row>` with columns having values `"null"`(null written text).
I am trying to replace the **"null"** text to text:**\N**.
For this I am using a logic that I will add a new column with name appended by "_nulled", e.g. column **abc** becomes **abc_nulled** and this new column will have the value **"\N"** if the current value is text **null** other wise the value remains the same.
For this I have used `withColumn(<new name>, when(col.equalTo("null"), "\\N").otherwise(<existing_value>))`.
How do I obtain this `<existing_value>`.
When I am passing `otherwise(ds.col(col_nm))` it is not working, possibly because it it expecting a `String` in `otherwise()` and finding a `Column`.

How should I resolve this? Here is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> newCols = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> reqColListCopy = Arrays.asList(reqCols);
Dataset<Row> testingDS = DS.selectExpr(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(reqColListCopy.iterator()).asScala().toSeq())

//Creating newCols (ArrayList so that I can add/remove column names.
Iterator itrTmp2 = reqColListCopy.iterator();
while(itrTmp2.hasNext()){
    newCols.add((String)itrTmp2.next());
}

//Creating a List reference for newCols ArrayList. This will be used to get Seq(<columns>).
List<String> newColsList = newCols;

Iterator colListItr = reqColListCopy.iterator();
while(colListItr.hasNext())
{
    String col = colListItr.next().toString();
    testingDS = testingDS.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(newColsList))
            .withColumn(col+"_nulled",  functions.when(testingDS.col(col).equalTo("null"), functions.lit("\\N")).otherwise(testingDS.col(col))) //'otherwise' needs a string parameter
            .drop(testingDS.col(col));

    newCols.add(col+"_nulled");
    newCols.remove(col);
    newColsList = newCols;
}
Dataset<Row> testingDS = DS.selectExpr(JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(newColsList.iterator()).asScala().toSeq())

testingDS.show(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by passing the column inside `lit()`:

```
.withColumn(col+"_nulled",  functions.when(testingDS.col(col).equalTo("null"), functions.lit("\\N")).otherwise(functions.lit(testingDS.col(col)))) //'otherwise' needs a string parameter
```

Comment: Is there a option to check for non null values? I actually want non null values to be placed in quotes and null not to be modified